# Forest function error - "argument 1 matches multiple formal arguments'

Tags: r, metafor

I created the following random-effects model, and am hoping to -for now anyway- generate a very basic forest plot, using the forest function from metafor.

This is the code I used:

`res <- rma(yi=Effect.Size, vi=var, data=full)

forest(x=res, vi, sei=se, ci.lb=low, ci.ub=hi)`

This is the error code I received:

`Error in forest(x = res, vi, sei = se, ci.lb = low, ci.ub = hi) :  argument 1 matches multiple formal arguments`

I have also tried switching out "x=res" for "x=Effect.Size" as the documentation states that either should work. However, both return the same error code.

Comment: Are you sure you should be passing `vi` into `forest`?

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is what I see on the documentation: forest(x, vi, sei, ci.lb, ci.ub,
       annotate=TRUE, showweights=FALSE, header=FALSE,
       xlim, alim, olim, ylim, at, steps=5,
       level=95, refline=0, digits=2L, width,
       xlab, slab, ilab, ilab.xpos, ilab.pos,
       order, subset, transf, atransf, targs, rows,
       efac=1, pch, psize, plim=c(0.5,1.5), col,
       lty, fonts, cex, cex.lab, cex.axis, ...)

Comment: You're calling the method `metafor::forest.rma`, which does not have `vi` as its second argument. That doesn't explain the error, though I would try not giving the `x=` tag for the first argument and just matching it by position.

Comment: As Thomas said -- there are multiple forest functions (or rather 'method functions'); see https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.rma.html and https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.default.html depending on the input. You are mixing together different arguments from these. I can't see how this error should arise with what you are doing, but then I would also need a fully reproducible example to diagnose this further.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! After many hours (maybe 8?) I gave up and used the ggplot2 instead for my forest plot. Still, thank you for your help.